# How to get a sum of all values from a node in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my Database structure:

[image: JSON]

I want to get the sum from all child values, from example for I want to get de value "5" that is the sum from all de values of the Node "UNICARIBE"

Comment: Paste your JSON code here...

Comment: I don't have a JSON code, just a photo of my database structure in firebase

Comment: Read the children, loop and sum... Have you tried?

Comment: I tried to get a value from individual children en then sum, but when I have a node with a lot of children this is so useful

Comment: I think thats the only option:- Read the children, loop and sum...as cricket_007 said . If you worry about the latency you can use Firebase Function on server side to do this and return the sum(Read the documentation first cause i haven't tried it yet ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count all those value, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference unicaribeRef = rootRef.child("Unicaribe");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int total = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int value = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
            total =+ value;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(total));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
unicaribeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be `5`.

Comment: Hey Alex Mamo, how i can  do this in python for a raspberry??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know Python.