# Firebase sum items from database

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i need to sum all items and price from my firebase database but every time i add item the sum multiply so what can i do to have the correct sum of items

```
cou.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postS: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                ProductVar productVar = postS.getValue(ProductVar.class);
                JumlaKuu += Integer.parseInt(productVar.getTotal());
                ItemsKuu += Integer.parseInt(productVar.getItem());


                Log.d("onVil2: ", String.valueOf(JumlaKuu));

            }
            jumla.setText(String.valueOf(JumlaKuu));
            itemsNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(ItemsKuu));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: try adding all value in array list and then sum them , and clear that list on every time snapshot called and  in end sum those valeus.?

Comment: With your current code it also adds the value of all the existing items, not only the newly added one. You should use a different listener (child) or set the value to 0 before getting the sum (again)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a sum of all values from a node in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626241/how-to-get-a-sum-of-all-values-from-a-node-in-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code old sum is also added into new one because you didn't set sum to 0 when your addValueEventListener gets fired. So, for getting correct sum every time you just have to set **JumlaKuu** & **ItemsKuu** values to 0 as below code.

```
cou.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            JumlaKuu = 0;
            ItemsKuu = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot postS: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                ProductVar productVar = postS.getValue(ProductVar.class);
                JumlaKuu += Integer.parseInt(productVar.getTotal());
                ItemsKuu += Integer.parseInt(productVar.getItem());


                Log.d("onVil2: ", String.valueOf(JumlaKuu));

            }
            jumla.setText(String.valueOf(JumlaKuu));
            itemsNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(ItemsKuu));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this.!

```
  final ArrayList<Integer> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();

    cou.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          int JumlaKuu =0;
          int ItemsKuu =0;

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                if (valuesList.size() > 0) {
                    valuesList.clear();
                }
                for (DataSnapshot postS : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ProductVar productVar = postS.getValue(ProductVar.class);
                    JumlaKuu += Integer.parseInt(productVar.getTotal());
                    ItemsKuu += Integer.parseInt(productVar.getItem());
                    valuesList.add(Integer.parseInt(productVar.getTotal()));

                    Log.d("onVil2: ", String.valueOf(JumlaKuu));

                }


            }



            jumla.setText(String.valueOf( getSum(valuesList)));
            itemsNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(ItemsKuu));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


   private int getSum(ArrayList<Integer> valuesList) {
    int sum = -1;

    for (Integer integer : valuesList) {
        sum = integer + sum;
    }

    return sum;

}
```