# Firebase Database retrieving sum of multiple childs

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to do sum of multiple child nodes in Firebase real-time database

[image]

Here is my database, in this I want to do sum of **"amount"** child, so how to do that?

Please Help!

Comment: Sounds possible. It should be fairly simple to read the data from the list, and get the amounts with this API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your database, your `amount` property is of type String and not number. So you cannot simply create a sum of String literals. To solve this you need to change your property name to be of type `number`. I also see that you are storing the currency along with the number. You should add the currency programmatically user side and not in the database. If you consider to change the type of your `amount` property, then please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626241/how-to-get-a-sum-of-all-values-from-a-node-in-firebase)**

However, if you want to keep your actual database structure, you can sum all amounts using the following trick:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int total = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String amount = ds.child("amount").getValue(String.class);
            int value = Integer.valueOf(amount.replace(" Rs.", ""));
            total =+ value;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(total) + " Rs.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
your_database_reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
27000
```

Comment: yeah got it, it works and thank you very much for the help..!

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase's addValueEventListener method for this and loop dataSnapshot to calculate total of each amount child

```
your_database_reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    int totalamount = 0;
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        // TODO: handle the dataSnapshot
        String amount = snapshot.child("amount").getValue();
        // remove _Rs. from amount and typecase it to int
        totalAmount += amount;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
});
```